# Odd (read) issue in Common Lisp (sbcl)

Tags: compilation, common-lisp

I have the following code:

```
(defun Areacircle ()
  (princ "Enter Radius: ")
  (defparameter radius (read))
  (defparameter area (* 3.1416 radius radius))
  (princ "Area: ")
  (write area))
(AreaCircle)
```

The problem is that, slime runs it with no problem but when I compile it with (compile-file "area.lisp" :output-file "area") it evaluates the (read) part first; it ask to pass the value to radius before printing anything.

Comment: Look into force-output.

Comment: Though not bad per se, it is unusual to use `defparameter` inside functions like you did. Also, I would write the function `circle-area`. Joshua Taylor is right about force-output (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your code is forcing the (buffered) output to be sent to the terminal. Adding a call to `(force-output)` or `(finish-output)` will help.

Additionally, you re using `defparameter` where you should be using `let`. You're possibly also better off using `pi` instead of your approximation and using `format` with a suitable format string to print the result.

Comment: That was a good lesson on good Lisp syntax, it solved my issue.